# Table which can add, edit ,and delete data dynamically in Drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, edit

I know that we can add edit and delete data in a table statically in Drupal. But is there any way we can add edit and delete data via clicking a link just near to each row so that on clicking "add " button should generate a new row, and on clicking edit should highlight all the contents of the row as fr editing and delete should remove the row. The basic table I created is this:

```
<?php
    $header = array('Emp ID', 'Emp Name', 'Emp Age');
    $rows = array();
    $sql = 'SELECT empid, name, age FROM {employee} ORDER BY name';
    $result = db_query($sql);
    while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
         $rows[] = $row;
    }
    print theme('table', $header, $rows);  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build it. You've already got your Read mode, so you need a Create/Update/Delete... there is some help on the internet for basic CRUD modules. Very basically, the update part, (first having a menu hook using % wildcard which is what arg(1) will be:

```
function crud_module_edit_form() {
  $result = db_select('employee', 'e')
    ->fields('e', array('empid', 'name'))
    ->condition('empid', arg(1), '=')
    ->orderBy('name', 'DESC')
    ->execute()
    ->fetch();

$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#default_value' => isset($result->name) ? $result->name : '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
return $form;
```

}

Then the submit function for the above form to update the record. You could use db_merge here instead and then use the same page for both the Add and the Update functions.

```
function crud_app_edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  db_update('employees')
    ->fields(array(
      'name' => check_plain($form_state['values']['name']),
    ))
    ->condition('empid', arg(1), '=')
    ->execute();

  drupal_set_message(t('Employee updated'));
}
```